# JSON table sorting value from key

Tags: php, json

i have a table like this

```
"6": {
  "11": {
    "rankPoints": 525,
    "matchesPlayed": 0,
    "tier": 0,
    "division": 0
  },
  "12": {
    "rankPoints": 375,
    "matchesPlayed": 0,
    "tier": 0,
    "division": 0
  },
  "13": {
    "rankPoints": 548,
    "matchesPlayed": 28,
    "tier": 8,
    "division": 0
  }}
```

i want to sort this table by tier value in php , how?

NOTE : i search for a way here but i didn't found what i want
sorry for my bad English :{

Comment: HOW ABOUT CONVERTING IN INTO AN ARRAY...& then using something like lodash...it make a neat code